# Getting similar Strings in PL/SQL with a good performance

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a big Table in my Oracle Database (12c) and I have a lot of Strings that need to be compared to each other. I want to see which Strings are similar.

Example:

**Hello World Boston in America**

**Hello World Berlin in Germany**

Should be detected as similiar Strings, while

**Hello World Paris in France**

**Hello Detroit a nice city**

should not be detected as similar.
How can I do this in Oracle PL/SQL efficiently and accurately?

Comment: you need to define some rules to say whether two stings are similar or not. will "hello world xx " and "hello world xx and yy " be similar? and "xx hello world"? and hello xx world" ? ... also, say you have 10 strings where everyone is similar to everyone else; what result would you expect? one row? 10 rows?, ...

Comment: Check out Oracle's built-in `UTL_MATCH` API. It provides a number of fast methods for comparing strings (Edit Distance, and Jaro Winkler). https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_MATCH.html#GUID-7F579819-995A-4E92-862A-3E9ED13AA236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Dice-Coefficient which has a nice balance between performance and efficiency. It will give you a NUMBER which represents how similar two strings are. You can run this Function for all of your strings comparing them to each other and then choose the ones which have a Big Coefficient (those will be very similar).

---

```
-- Dice-Coefficient in Oracle PL/SQL
-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice%27s_coefficient
-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen_similarity_index
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION DICE_COEFF(p_str1 IN VARCHAR2, p_str2 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
    co_substr_len CONSTANT NUMBER := 2;

    TYPE ty_varchar_assoc IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);

    v_x     ty_varchar_assoc;
    v_y     ty_varchar_assoc;
    v_inter ty_varchar_assoc;
    v_part  VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN

    -- building set X
    FOR i IN 1 .. length(p_str1) - co_substr_len + 1 LOOP
      v_part := substr(p_str1, i, co_substr_len);
      v_x(v_part) := v_part;
    END LOOP;

    -- building set Y
    FOR i IN 1 .. length(p_str2) - co_substr_len + 1 LOOP
      v_part := substr(p_str2, i, co_substr_len);
      v_y(v_part) := v_part;

      IF v_x.exists(v_part) THEN
        v_inter(v_part) := v_part; -- build intersect            
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 2 * v_inter.count /(v_x.count + v_y.count);

END DICE_COEFF;
```